# Numpy Modular arithmetic

Tags: python, numpy, math, modular

How can I define in numpy a matrix that uses operations modulo 2?

For example:

```
0 0       1 0       1 0
1 1   +   0 1   =   1 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This operation is called "xor".

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.array([[0,0],[1,1]])
>>> y = numpy.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
>>> x ^ y
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

BTW, (element-wise) multiplication modulo 2 can be done with "and".

```
>>> x & y
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass `numpy.ndarray` and override the `__add__` method, but I think it would be far simpler to just be explicit. For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,0],[1,1]])
y = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])

print (x + y) % 2
```

Which yields:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: I also need the modular addition when multiplying two matrices

Comment: @Yassin - Then just do `(x * y) % 2`. Kenny's solution is the way to go, though... I tend to forget that xor and the like exist! It's a cleaner way to do what you want.